# What are the sources of the popularity of the urban slang term "shank"?

Tags: etymology, slang

> *to shank* to stab with an improvised knife

How did *shank* evolve to its importance in popular culture?  Has there been a key gangster rap with this word, perhaps taking off as an internet sensation?

---

The suspected duplicate isn't the same as my question.  I'm looking for something recent, to trace its recent extreme popularity.

Comment: I think the term came from a 19th century convict who had trouble pronouncing his THs (you know, things became sings, thin became sin, etc.). One day he said sarcastically to a fellow inmate who had dissed him, "Shank you very much," at which point the fellow inmate stabbed him with a homemade knife. Thereafter, the knife became known as a "shank you very much." Over time, the phrase was shortened to "shank." Don

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cqi8-HlHmLU

Comment: I believe "shiv" is another term with similar meaning (though probably only as a noun), though Wikipedia et al indicate it covers a wider range of possible forms, while my recollection from it's (rarer) use in TV/movies is that it's usually something easily concealed (in addition to being improvised as is the shank).

Answer (score 2):

A quick trip back to origins might be required before tackling that part of the question relating to current common usage.

Firstly, to set aside some fanciful speculation, *'shank'* in the sense of home-made knife, or the act of stabbing, is unlikely to have developed from a practice of sharpening leg (or *'shank'*) bones into knives.  *'Shank'* has long usage as a descriptor for any straight thin section of an object.  As the OED has it:

> 5. The stem or straight part of anything. Cf. shaft n.2a. The stem of a goblet, glass, etc.
>      *1553 Inv. Ch. Goods York, etc. (Surtees) 168 The foote, shancke, and knoppe of the challaice. 1583–4 New Yrs. Gifts in Nichols Progr. Eliz. (1823) II. 420 Oone sault, the foote, shainke, and cover of lapis-lazule. 1625 in Rymer Fœdera XVIII. 238/1 One Salte of Goulde..haveing uppon the Shanke three great course Saphires. 1826 Galt Last of Lairds iii. 28 He had the shank o' the very glass in his hand he had held to his old frien's lips.*

*'Shank'* is in its oldest sense related to the word *'Shaft'*, again as the OED explains:

> ▪ II.shaft, n.2
>   (ʃɑːft, -æ-)
>   Forms: 1 sceft, 1–3 sceaft, scæft, 3 scaft, saft, 3–4 ssafte, scheft, 4 shafth, 4–5 schafft, schafte, 4–7 schaft, shafte, 5 chaft(e, 4– shaft; rare 4 schaf, 4–5 shaffe, 4, 7 shaff, 7 shafe.
>   [Com. Teut. (wanting in Gothic): OE. sceaft masc. = OFris. skeft (Hettema), OS. skaft masc. (MLG., MDu., Du. schaft, schacht fem.), OHG. scaft masc., pl. scefti (MHG., mod.G. schaft masc.), ON. skapt neut. (Sw., Da. skaft):—OTeut. *skafto-, *skafti-z:—preTeut. *skapto-, -ti-s.
>   **App. cogn. w. L. scāpus shaft, stem, shank**; somewhat more doubtfully with Gr. (Dor.) σκᾶπτον staff (Ion., Att. σκηπτο- in σκηπτοῦχος staff-bearer, σκῆπτρον staff, sceptre, σκήπτειν to prop.). The Teut. word might, with regard both to form and meaning, be plausibly explained as a passive ppl. derivative from the root of shave v.; but it is doubtful whether the supposed cognates can be similarly accounted for.]

Prison *'shanks'* can be made from the straight sections of handle of toothbrushes and spoons and various tools including screwdrivers.  It is interesting to note that a knife and fork were not commonly issued items in early prisons, but a spoon (and mug or bowl) was almost ubiquitous.

The word has very widespread use in US and Australian jails, and the suggested path of the term into common culture is the extremely high rate of imprisonment in the US, and the connection between some street culture and its music with street gangs and prison culture.  A search of Rap Music lyrics suggests that the term is widespread, and the suggestion is that it was not a novel word to people who wrote or listened to this music, but rather part of their everyday language.

It is rap music which has brought the word into wider awareness, such that we are talking about it here, but it has for a very long time been a very specific term in the criminal and prison fraternities.

Comment: Your last two paragraphs start to get to my question.  I'm looking for something more specific.  This term is very hot right now and I wonder if there's a particular song or video that ignited the current craze.

Comment: I agree that my answer is unsatisfactory, but proving the negative (that there was **no** single event) is much harder than proving that there was.  But, inspired by your interest, I'll labour a little longer at the task and see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the errors in my spelling in the original - very embarrassing and I can only put it down to suffering at the moment from a very bad head cold.

Comment: Yes, to my (white, middle-class) knowledge "shank", in the sense of an improvised knife-like weapon used in a prison, goes back at least 50 years (and likely much farther).  It's a relatively common term (as both noun and verb) in the dialog of TV shows and movies about prisons and criminal activity, so even people with no direct experience in prisons would know of it.  That it might become a common term in "street culture" is totally unsurprising.